# Listening to form value changes called frequently

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have three from controls,

- firstname,
- LastName
- customformcontrol

The custom formcontrol is a simple counter that increments or decrement a value in an inputbox.
 I listen to value changes of the whole form .The problem is when i include this the custom form control, The form value changes triggered on some scenario's like when other  input tag's get focus or on click of the body of the document or on page scroll. I know the value change is only subscribed to value changes of any of the formcontrols in the form but it also triggers on weird cases  as mentioned above.

Here is what i have tried,

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.profileForm.valueChanges.subscribe( x => {
      console.log('value changing');
    })
}
```

Here is the [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nxum25?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) on stackblitz

Here are the steps to reproduce the issue,
click on the firstname and then click on lastname and you will see the console log messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this was very odd behavior to me, so I immediately checked your custom formControl, and I find out that you calling

```
  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    this.propagateChange(this.counterValue);
  }
```

> **ngAfterContentChecked** - Respond after Angular checks the content projected into the directive/component. Called after the
>   ngAfterContentInit() and every subsequent ngDoCheck().

So, the problem here is that this hook calling after ngDoCheck

> **ngDoCheck()** Detect and act upon changes that Angular can't or won't detect on its
>   own.
>
> Called during every change detection run, immediately after
>   ngOnChanges() and ngOnInit().

So basically, every change detection run this form control emits the event. 
You should delete this from the custom control, and you will remain the same basic behavior without the endless loop that calling your emits.

Comment: I need the solution for this issue. But I don't get what you're trying convey...Can be more specific or provide a sample code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do some hacking to check form input values are not same. 
Here is the updated stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7bxnw1

Comment: This is not a solutions because this function is called frequently.

Comment: Look at your code on stackblitz. The issue is same.https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w7wagc?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use updateOn: 'blur' when you create a reactive form with [FormBuilder](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder).
About [updateOn](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControlOptions#abstractcontroloptions). You can use it on a field(FormControl) and a form(FormGroup).